# pg_config not found in path with brew

Tags: macos, postgresql, homebrew

I am trying to install gdal with brew on OSX Mavericks. However, I get the following error:

```
brew install gdal
==> Installing dependencies for gdal: liblwgeom, libspatialite
==> Installing gdal dependency: liblwgeom
==> Downloading http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/source/postgis-2.1.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/liblwgeom-2.1.1.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://gist.github.com/dakcarto/7458788/raw/8df39204eef5a1e5671828ded7f377ad
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/liblwgeom--patch-3d93c9ede79439f1c683a604f9d906f5c788c690.diff
==> Patching
patching file configure.ac
==> ./autogen.sh
==> ./configure --disable-nls --with-projdir=/usr/local --with-jsondir=/usr/local/opt/json-c 
checking for iconv_open in -liconv... yes
checking for iconvctl... no
checking for libiconvctl... no
checking for pg_config... no
configure: error: could not find pg_config within the current path. You may need to try re-running configure with a --with-pg_config parameter.

READ THIS: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
```

I tried to install it again with:

```
brew install gdal --with-pg-config='/usr/local/bin/pg_config'
```

but I get the same error:

```
brew install gdal --with-pg-config='/usr/local/bin/pg_config'
==> Installing dependencies for gdal: liblwgeom, libspatialite
==> Installing gdal dependency: liblwgeom
==> Downloading http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/source/postgis-2.1.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/liblwgeom-2.1.1.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://gist.github.com/dakcarto/7458788/raw/8df39204eef5a1e5671828ded7f377ad
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/liblwgeom--patch-3d93c9ede79439f1c683a604f9d906f5c788c690.diff
==> Patching
patching file configure.ac
==> ./autogen.sh
==> ./configure --disable-nls --with-projdir=/usr/local --with-jsondir=/usr/local/opt/json-c 
checking for iconv_open in -liconv... yes
checking for iconvctl... no
checking for libiconvctl... no
checking for pg_config... no
configure: error: could not find pg_config within the current path. You may need to try re-running configure with a --with-pg_config parameter.

READ THIS: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
```

Both postgres and postgresql have been installed successfully.

Comment: What does `which pg_config` say? Does `/usr/local/bin/pg_config` do anything?

Comment: Just updated the output to my post. Thanks.

Comment: error messages says `--with-pg_config` not `--with-pg-config`, or you could even add `/usr/local/bin` to `PATH`

Comment: Ah, good catch. Yep, get the same exact error. And the command "which pg_config" says, "/usr/local/bin/pg_config"

Comment: I'm seeing this same error on a brand new machine trying to set up postgresql and postgis from Homebrew...

Comment: I cannot quite explain but I uninstalled and reinstalled homebrww and then tried installing gdal. It worked!